# ASP.NET Razor page, change color of particular row of table based on conditions?

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, razor-pages

I have a table something like this.

```
 <tbody>
   @foreach (var item in Model)
       {
           <tr>
               <td>
                   // Some data displayed
               </td>
           </tr>
       }
  </tbody>
```

In the `foreach` loop, `item` contains one parameter like `MyId`. It can be either any integer `INT` or `NULL`.
I would like to change background color of that particular  row if it is an integer.
For eg: 
if `item.MyId` is any integer, then display that row background as blue. 
If `item.MyId` is `NULL` then display Grey.

How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 4):

```
<tbody>
   @foreach (var item in Model)
       {
           <tr style="background:@(item.MyId is null ? "grey" : "blue");">
               <td>
                   // Some data displayed
               </td>
           </tr>
       }
  </tbody>
```